# Write list of strings to a file (as lines)?

Tags: export

I have a list of Strings, like:

```
list = {"hello", "world", "other line"};
```

And I want to write it to a file, so that each item in `list` gets written to a new line. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `Export[StringRiffle[list, "\n"], "Text"]` should work.

Comment: Also `Export["file.txt", list, "List"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by C.E. in comments,

```
Export["file.txt", StringRiffle[list, "\n"], "Text"]
```

gives a text file like

> hello
>
> world
>
> other line

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `WriteLine`.

> Update. I added RunnyKine's solution for completeness.

Little benchmark:

```
list = ToString /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000000];

writeList[name_, list_] := Module[{file},
   file = OpenWrite[name];
   WriteLine[file, #] & /@ list;
   Close[file]
   ];
writeList2[name_, list_] := Module[{file},
   file = OpenWrite[name, FormatType -> OutputForm]; 
   WriteString[file, Sequence @@ StringRiffle[list, "\n"]]
    Close[file]
   ];



First@AbsoluteTiming@
  Export["test1", StringRiffle[list, "\n"], "Text"]
First@AbsoluteTiming[writeList2["test2", list]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[writeList["test3", list]]
First@AbsoluteTiming@Export["test4", list, "List"]

0.76902
0.987253
5.92252
13.9983
```

Amazing how slow the `Export[...,"List"]` is...

Comment: OR slightly faster: `str = OpenWrite["test.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm]; WriteString[str, Sequence @@ StringRiffle[list, "\n"]]`

Comment: @RunnyKine the `Export["test3", StringRiffle[list, "\n"], "Text"]` is faster than your solution (at least on my machine)

Comment: What are your timings? It's slightly faster than Export on my machine and definitely much faster than WriteLine.

Comment: @RunnyKine I updated my answer. It's much faster than `WriteLine` indeed.

Comment: Interesting. Well, I get 1.68071 for `writeList2` vs 1.78251 for `Export[... "Text"]`.

Comment: @RunnyKine Version/OS probably... Have MMA 10.0 on Mac

Comment: Have 10.4.1 on Windows 10

Comment: When you read back that file using e.g. `res = ReadList["test.txt", Number];`, do you get back the same number of elements i.e. is `Length @ res == 1000000`? This is not related to the speed difference just curious cos I get a different number. I figured what was causing the speed issue: `StringRiffle`.

Comment: @RunnyKine Actually I do get different lengths... interesting

Comment: Hmm. That is interesting.

Comment: Slightly faster (on my system) `First@AbsoluteTiming@
  Export["/tmp/test0", StringRiffle[list, "\n"], "String"]`

Comment: If anyone else runs this and notices there are more than 1000000 lines in the output file, it is due to ToString of small numbers producing exponential notation formatted across two lines.